# Is there a way to group separate "resuming" ordered-list elements to indicate that they are all related?

Tags: html

For reasons that are unclear to me, I find myself in the position of having HTML that looks like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>...</li>
</ol>


 ... stuff

<ol start="2">
  <li>...</li>
</ol>

... more stuff

<ol start="3">
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

Yuck, right? Well, I have to live with it for now; I will work on flipping all of this inside-out at some point to make "proper" lists in the future but `#deadlines`.

Since I'm chopping this "list" into several separate lists, is there a way to indicate that they are all part of the same list? I'm mostly thinking of screen-readers and other assistive technologies which like to know when things like lists are continuous even if they are distinct structural elements in the page.

Comment: Not related but I thought I let you know that you have a small typo in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276232/christopher-schultz)  `Cheif Technology Officer` -> `Chief Technology Officer`

Answer (score 0):

You could set a custom data attribute in your `<ol>` elements and then retrieve them in JS with a querySelectorAll like this:

```js
let elementsQuery = document.querySelectorAll('ol[data-list="list1"]');
let nodes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < elementsQuery.length; i++) {
  nodes.push(elementsQuery[i]);
}
console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<ol data-list="list1">
    <li>...</li>
</ol>


 ... stuff

<ol start="2" data-list="list1">
  <li>...</li>
</ol>

... more stuff

<ol start="3" data-list="list1">
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: So that will let *me* fetch all the lists together as one... but I have no need to do that. I'm wondering if there is a way to "help" things like assistive technologies understand that these separate lists are related to each other.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't quite get your question the first time. After searching a bit I found that you can specify which element the screen reader should read next and override the default behaviour with the attribute `aria-flowto`. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-flowto

Comment: Here are some examples: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-flowto . If you find this helpful I will edit the answer.

Comment: I looked at the ARIA things a little before posting, but they didn't seem relevant – perhaps simply because I don't have any experience with them. In my case, the existing page-flow is actually *correct*. I just have separate `<ol>` elements where, really, only a single `<ol>` element should be present containing all of the items.